# Spring Native build with GCP failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-native

I am trying to build a native version of my Spring Boot app (3.0.6, Java 17, Gradle 7.5) using Spring Native. The target runtime is Cloud Run on the GCP. When I try to run the Gradle task 'bootBuildImage', I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MissingParametersCompilerArgumentException: Constructor binding in a native image requires compilation with -parameters but the following classes were compiled without it:
    com.google.cloud.spring.core.Credentials

    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindableRuntimeHintsRegistrar.registerHints(BindableRuntimeHintsRegistrar.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanFactoryInitializationAotProcessor$ConfigurationPropertiesReflectionHintsContribution.applyTo(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanFactoryInitializationAotProcessor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
```

I think that the Spring Native build process already includes the "-parameters" flag by default. Is this correct? If so, the problem could be related to the com.google.cloud.spring.core.Credentials class, which may have been compiled without the "-parameters" flag.

This is an example of a gradle.build file that generates the same error:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.20'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudGcpVersion', "4.1.4")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Update:
Okay, it looks like there is currently no support for Spring Native through the GCP libs:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed in the current version of the GCP Spring starter package.