# Constructor binding in a native image requires compilation with -parameters but the following classes were compiled without it: okhttp3.Protocol

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okhttp, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to create a spring-boot 3 native graalvm image using `mvn clean native:compile` but I'm getting the following error:

```
Constructor binding in a native image requires compilation with -parameters but the following classes were compiled without it:
    okhttp3.Protocol
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindableRuntimeHintsRegistrar.registerHints(BindableRuntimeHintsRegistrar.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanFactoryInitializationAotProcessor$ConfigurationPropertiesReflectionHintsContribution.applyTo(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanFactoryInitializationAotProcessor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
```

I don't understand what the error message means. What am I supposed to do with "-parameters"? I can't find any documentation about that. Is `okhttp3.Protocol` the one that's compiling well or the one not compiling?
Any help is much appreciated.

Environment:
OS: Windows 10 x64 22H2
JDK: GraalVM CE 22.3.2 with Open JDK 17.0.7
Maven: 3.9.1
Spring-Boot: 3.1.0-RC1
okhttp: 5.0.0-alpha.11

I tried to update okhttp to the newest version (from an older one) but it didn't change the error.

I found a few posts with similar errors ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071418/spring-native-build-with-gcp-failed), [[2]](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/776)) that conclude that the mentioned package is the problem. Removing the package is not really an option for me as I need okhttp as a dependency for other dependencies. The posts also don't talk about "-parameters".

[[3]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33182) discusses "-parameters" but doesn't discuss how to use it for an error similar to mine so I don't understand how to use "-parameters" to fix my issue.

Comment: if you put a reproducer, it will be easier to investigate.